# TypeError: scheduler.do is not a function using blob.uploadStream

Tags: angular, azure, npm, azure-blob-storage

Used [Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob#create-a-blob-by-uploading-data)

I am trying to upload a blob to the azure blob storage using

```
blockBlobClient.uploadStream()
```

However, the package throws this error:

```
TypeError: scheduler.do is not a function
at BlockBlobClient.uploadStream (Clients.js:1954)
```

My code is:

```
    const blockBlobClient = sourceClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
    const blockSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // the block size in the uploaded block blob
    const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(file, blockSize, 20, {onProgress: (ev) => console.log(ev)});
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're calling `uploadStream` method from a browser however it is only available in Node.JS runtime. From the code comments [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/4da08a15a6fe25063854020cd7f8f685df4cd4ca/sdk/storage/storage-blob/src/Clients.ts#L4352):

```
  /**
   * ONLY AVAILABLE IN NODE.JS RUNTIME.
   *
   * Uploads a Node.js Readable stream into block blob.
   *
   * PERFORMANCE IMPROVEMENT TIPS:
   * * Input stream highWaterMark is better to set a same value with bufferSize
   *    parameter, which will avoid Buffer.concat() operations.
   *
   * @param stream - Node.js Readable stream
   * @param bufferSize - Size of every buffer allocated, also the block size in the uploaded block blob. Default value is 8MB
   * @param maxConcurrency -  Max concurrency indicates the max number of buffers that can be allocated,
   *                                 positive correlation with max uploading concurrency. Default value is 5
   * @param options - Options to Upload Stream to Block Blob operation.
   * @returns Response data for the Blob Upload operation.
   */
  public async uploadStream(
```

The method you would want to use for uploading is [`uploadBrowserData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#uploadBrowserData_Blob___ArrayBuffer___ArrayBufferView__BlockBlobParallelUploadOptions_) or [`uploadData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#uploadData_Buffer___Blob___ArrayBuffer___ArrayBufferView__BlockBlobParallelUploadOptions_) when you are using this SDK in a browser-based application.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I didn't check that out.